# Tax calculation in Norway for married couple

Tags: taxes, salary, norway, tax-deductions

How the taxes are calculated in Norway for married couple?
If my monthly salary is 55,000 NOK and my spouse's monthly salary is 28,000 NOK, then

a) Should we taxed together or separately?

b) What should be tax table/tax bracket and what should be final in hand salary in a month?

Comment: What research have you done already? Eg online https://www.nordisketax.net/main.asp?url=files/nor/eng/i12.asp

Comment: Which languages can you read? Is for example https://www.smartepenger.no/skatt/617-ektefeller-og-skatt comprehensible?

Comment: Don't forget, as well as tax, there may be a deduction for social security, for health insurance, and for pension (possibly both state and private).  Even a "church tax" in some countries.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate your taxes using this webpage of the Norwegian tax authority: https://skattekalkulator.app.skatteetaten.no - switch to English in the upper right corner.

This uses the same engine as the actual tax calculation, it should be correct.

Norway has only few rules that give benefits to married people; every married couple is automatically taxed together but it has few consequences.

Comment: *Usually* if married couples are taxed together, then the tax free allowances and all the bands are doubled - which favours couples who have significantly dissimilar salaries (because the higher earner can use the rest of the lower-earners unused low salary bands, so less is taxed at the higher rate).

Comment: Not in Norway, where income is always taxed individually (since 2018) unless one person makes less then ca 50000 NOK what gives a minimal advantage. The only real advantage is in property taxes.